# React.Js how to display price based on dropdown selection?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I really need help, I'm stuck on this matter for over 2 days and so far nobody was able to help me.

I'm trying to do one thing only: **I have an e-commerce shop where there's multiple items**. Each item can have **multiple options like quantity: 300g, 500g and 1000g.** **I want to display the price of that item based on the quantity that's selected**. I have all the data in my own API. Here's a photo so you can clearly see what I'm trying to do:

[image]

and here's some relevant code.

**1) How each item looks like in my json file:**

```js
{
            id: '233fdcc3',
            nume: 'Adimel',
            slug: 'adimel',
            categorie: 'ingrasaminte',
            imagine: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1609361528183-1acc0d399845?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=687&q=80',
            pret: [
                {'300g': 25.00},
                {'500g': 32.00},
                {'1000g': 44.00},
            ],
            descriere: 'lorem ipsum blaboajsojas saf sfa fas fasfgaiasfagagjgoajg afaoj foasf jafo afo afdgagagdg a a',
            inStoc: 5,
            reducere: '10%',
},
```

^ As you can see above, **"pret" is an array that contains key value pairs.**

Then, here's my **product page code**:

I have set useState because I'm assuming price always changes based on the selection like this:

```js
const [currentProductPrice, setCurrentProductPrice] = useState('');
```

and then **part of my component code is here**(I highlighted the part that I had no idea how to do)

```js
<QuantityInput name='cantitate' onChange={handleChange}>
                    {product.pret.map(valoare => (
                        <Optiune key={Math.random(10)} value={Object.keys(valoare)}>{Object.keys(valoare)}</Optiune>
                    ))}
                    
                </QuantityInput>
            </QuantitySelector>
            <TotalPriceAndQuantity>
                <TotalPrice>
                    Total: 
                    {???????}
                    </TotalPrice>
```

I've also made a function like this

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value); 
}
```

and it works perfectly, i only get the keys, but **how do I set the price based on the key selected**?

HUGE thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure what you exactly want but if you want to a quantity and want to get the price of this quantity you can add this code .

```
<QuantityInput name='cantitate' onChange={handleChange}>
    {product.pret.map(valoare => (
       <Optiune key={Math.random(10)} value={Object.values(valoare)}> 
             {Object.keys(valoare)} and price is {Object.values(valoare)} 
        </Optiune>
                ))}
                
 </QuantityInput>
```

if you want to show both price and quantity you can add this code

Comment: Yes, that works perfectly, but then how can I update the price state of the item so that it can go into other components? (For example in the cart). Because when I try to take the Object.values(valoare) out of this components, it says “valoare” is not declared :(